# nodejs throwing ENOMEM when 'exec'ing zip process

Tags: node.js, zip, child-process

I am trying to zip a directory in nodejs.  I know that there are other ways to zip a file but I am stuck with this for now.

```
  var child = exec("zip -r " + zipFile + " " + zipDirectory, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err !== null) {
      console.log('error generating zip: ' + err);
    }

    // do some stuff with the created zip file
  });
```

I am running this on a server with a tiny amount of memory but since I am 'exec'ing a process outside of nodejs I would never expect nodejs to throw an ENOMEM exception.

This works when my server tries and zip up a small directory, however if it tries to zip up a directory with a few videos in it I get the exception.

I have tried to run the 'zip' command on the command line on the server.  It works just fine.

I have tried spawn instead of exec as well with the same problem.

The interesting part is that the exec command fails almost instantly, i.e. its not like it starts creating the zip file and then runs out of memory.

Why would exec require more memory for a bigger zip?

Comment: I am having the same issue. However, I am using an older copy of node on an embedded system. (0.6.21)